# Jest RTL tests passing but getting Process finished with exit code 1 intermittently

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

My tests are all passing successfully, at least in practise. I ran the tests 20 times and 19 times it passed. Once it failed, the code had not changed. I have still not been able to narrow this down, however as soon as I remove the async/wait test, it will pass 100% of the time: `it('displays a validation error on missing email address', async () => { ....  expect(await screen.findByText(emailRequired)).toBeInTheDocument()`

I am asking, how can I have the tests consistently pass when the tests should always pass?

#### package.json

```
"test": "react-scripts test --watchAll=false --no-cache --runInBand",
```

### cmd

```
hutber@hutber:/var/www/target/broker-dashboard$ yarn test src/pages/ForgotPassword/ForgotPassword.test.tsx
yarn run v1.22.17
$ react-scripts test --watchAll=false --no-cache --runInBand src/pages/ForgotPassword/ForgotPassword.test.tsx
 PASS  src/pages/ForgotPassword/ForgotPassword.test.tsx
  Test the ForgotPassword page
    ✓ renders without error (115 ms)
    ✓ displays an email input (30 ms)
    ✓ displays a validation error on missing email address (62 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.236 s
Ran all test suites matching /src\/pages\/ForgotPassword\/ForgotPassword.test.tsx/i.
Done in 3.74s.
hutber@hutber:/var/www/target/broker-dashboard$ yarn test src/pages/ForgotPassword/ForgotPassword.test.tsx
yarn run v1.22.17
$ react-scripts test --watchAll=false --no-cache --runInBand src/pages/ForgotPassword/ForgotPassword.test.tsx
 PASS  src/pages/ForgotPassword/ForgotPassword.test.tsx
  Test the ForgotPassword page
    ✓ renders without error (194 ms)
    ✓ displays an email input (50 ms)
    ✓ displays a validation error on missing email address (106 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.551 s
Ran all test suites matching /src\/pages\/ForgotPassword\/ForgotPassword.test.tsx/i.
Done in 4.06s.
hutber@hutber:/var/www/target/broker-dashboard$ yarn test src/pages/ForgotPassword/ForgotPassword.test.tsx
yarn run v1.22.17
$ react-scripts test --watchAll=false --no-cache --runInBand src/pages/ForgotPassword/ForgotPassword.test.tsx

 RUNS  src/pages/ForgotPassword/ForgotPassword.test.tsx
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

You will see that tests are marked as "RUNS" i.e they don't actually fail, but possible timeout and then get reported as failing.

#### Test

```
import { render, fireEvent, act, waitFor, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import { MemoryRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { StoreProvider } from 'easy-peasy'
import store from 'store'
import { SnackbarProvider } from 'notistack'
import { SnackbarUtilsConfigurator } from 'appContext/SnackbarUtils'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material'
import { theme } from 'themes'

import ForgotPassword from '.'

const Component = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <StoreProvider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <SnackbarProvider anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}>
            <ForgotPassword />
            <SnackbarUtilsConfigurator />
          </SnackbarProvider>
        </Router>
      </StoreProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

describe('Test the ForgotPassword page', () => {
  it('renders without error', () => {
    render(<Component />)
    expect(screen.getByText('forgot_password_header')).toBeTruthy()
  })

  /*
   ** NOTE: the use of i18n.t in UNIT TESTS with Yup doesn't work - so use the
   ** translation instead of the key, but only in the unit tests, it's ok in the
   ** schema. It's currently unknown what happens if there are multiple languages.
   */

  it('displays an email input', () => {
    render(<Component />)
    const expected = screen.getByText('appHeader.lbl_noAccount')
    expect(expected).toBeInTheDocument()
  })

  const emailRequired = /email is required/i
  const emailInvalid = /enter a valid email/i

  it('displays a validation error on missing email address', async () => {
    render(<Component />)
    expect(screen.queryByText(emailRequired)).not.toBeInTheDocument()
    const emailFormInput = screen.getByTestId('email-form-input')
    fireEvent.blur(emailFormInput)
    expect(await screen.findByText(emailRequired)).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```